# How do I control the order files are loaded in karma config

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm testing an Angular app with Karma.  I've got everything working, but it seems like I'm doing something wrong.

https://gist.github.com/guyjacks/7bca850844deb612e681

Karma will throw the following error if I comment out 'app/notes/notes.main.js' :

Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'notes.main' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
  http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/nomod?p0=notes.main
  at /Users/guyjacks/projects/adr-demo/node_modules/angular/angular.js:1958

I don't want to have to manually list each application file to control the order in which each file loads.  Am I don't something wrong or do I just have to list each file in the order I want?

---- Solution based on the accepted answer ----

My app is organized into modules as recommended by the Angular Style Guide: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide.

```
'app/app.module.js',
'app/**/*.module.js',
'app/**/*.service.js',
'app/**/*.controller.js',
'app/**/*.directive.js',
'app/**/*.js'
```

I don't think the following lines are necessary above

```
'app/**/*.service.js', 
'app/**/*.controller.js',
'app/**/*.directive.js'
```

when each module has an angular module declared in the *.module.js file like my app does.

That said, if you did need to explicitly load services before controllers & controllers before directives then this would be the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** : I could not see your karma file, now Gist link is fixed.

The point in notes[.]main.js is causing the problem,

So, 'app/**/*.js' is not matching notes.main.js.

Try now like this : app/**/*. *.js

=============================================================

**Before update :**

You have to load the modules that you app depends on, in karma config. file :

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

   .......

   // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
   files: [
    './client/app/vendors/angular/angular.js',

    // =====>  load Your modules here ...

    './client/app/app.js',
    './client/app/controllers/*.js',
    './client/app/directives/*.js',
    './client/app/services/*.js',
    './test/client/unit/**/*.js'
],
.....

}) }
```

Comment: FYI, its not a recommended convention to organize an app by the type of component (services, controllers, etc...).

Comment: Is this solving your main problem (modules not loaded when firing tests ...) ??? For the file structure subject, "this is just an exemple" on how to load your files not how to strcuture apps, and by the way this is a small angular app. "organizing by features" a 4 files makes no sense (I will not be lost inside in this app ...). You use a convention/recommendation when there is the conditions (large apps here ...) to apply it.

Comment: I updaed my answer based on your Gist. :)